# gcc 4.8.2 make error on CentOS 6

Tags: linux, gcc

When I was trying make and make install gcc 4.8.2 on my CentOS 6 server, I received this error information.

I do have no clue what is going on. Could anyone help me out with this?

Many Thanks!

```
g++ -c   -g -DIN_GCC   -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE -I. -Ibuild -I../.././gcc -I../.././gcc/build -I../.././gcc/../include -I../.././gcc/../libcpp/include -I/root/gcc-4.8.2/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gmp -I/root/gcc-4.8.2/gmp -I/root/gcc-4.8.2/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/mpfr -I/root/gcc-4.8.2/mpfr -I/root/gcc-4.8.2/mpc/src  -I../.././gcc/../libdecnumber -I../.././gcc/../libdecnumber/bid -I../libdecnumber -I../.././gcc/../libbacktrace    \
        -o build/genattrtab.o ../.././gcc/genattrtab.c
g++   -g -DIN_GCC   -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE  -o build/genattrtab \
        build/genattrtab.o build/rtl.o build/read-rtl.o build/ggc-none.o build/vec.o     build/min-insn-modes.o build/gensupport.o build/print-rtl.o build/read-md.o build/errors.o ../../build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libiberty/libiberty.a
build/genattrtab ../.././gcc/config/i386/i386.md insn-conditions.md \
        -Atmp-attrtab.c -Dtmp-dfatab.c -Ltmp-latencytab.c
make[3]: *** [s-attrtab] Killed
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/gcc-4.8.2/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc'
make[2]: *** [all-stage1-gcc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/gcc-4.8.2'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/gcc-4.8.2'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Your compilation was killed by either the OOM killer or another server admin.

Comment: [Read](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter05/gcc-pass1.html) [through](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter05/gcc-pass2.html) the [relevant](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter06/gcc.html) chapters of the LFS, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

is it 32bit or 64bit?

I recommend taking a look [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48378).  Quite a few suggestsions:

1.Make sure you aren't trying to build in the source directories

2.Suggestion to install the glibc headers and libs first, you can install this with debuginfo however more details can be found [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Glibc-Install-HOWTO/):

```
 debuginfo-install glibc
```